# Difference between Foreground Service and JobScheduler

Tags: android

I have an app where I use a foreground service to start a number N of threads that sleep most of the time and sometimes wake up to do some measurements.

I used foreground services because I need that these measurements must be done at specific and exact time without background limitations introduced by Android 8.0.

This seems to work and from documentation seems that there are no problem, but I read also about JobScheduler.

There is an advantage to use Jobs to schedule work at specific accurate time or my solution can be used without problems.

Comment: Jobs don't run at exact time - system can postpone them as it sees fit, usually to batch more jobs together and complete them within one cpu wake up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First a fact**

In `JobScheduler`, the System execute your Job(Task) in application's `JobService`
and the `JobService` class also extend the same `Service` class that we use to define `Foreground Service`. So by using the both, we can execute code in background

Now the main difference is, `Foreground Service` is always running(by showing notification to user) and consuming the battery and memory of the user even, if your threads are sleeping and no code is executing.

As it's running always you can do whatever you want precisely at any moment of time. maybe it's good for your app's point of view but it's bad for user. your app draining the battery unnecessarily and consuming the RAM.

To address this problem we got `JobScheduler`. you can Schedule a job to be executed based on some criteria. Your app will only wake when the criteria is met, but it's not precise.it depends on many factors like doze mode etc.

you can look more about that [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/)

**The conclusion is**

If your task is not needed to be execute at exact time then you should use `JobScheduler` (recently `WorkManager` is better as it use `JobScheduler` internally and more advance) to save your user's battery

and according official [document](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)

> WorkManager is intended for tasks that are deferrable—that is, not
>   required to run immediately—and required to run reliably even if the
>   app exits or the device restarts.

Comment: First of all thank you for your explanation, I didn't know that with JobScheduler the scheduling is not precise. I thought that using JobInfo.Builder's methods setMinimumLatency(long) and setOverrideDeadline(long) jobs would have been executed at correct time.
Probably I'm going a little bit off topic, but this behavior of JobScheduler is the reason why I must choose my solution with ForegroundService and threads? Or do you know if there is a better tool in Android Framework that is better for my use case (accurate time scheduling)?

Comment: @Beruth if your requirement is to run at exact time say 11:30AM then use AlarmManager However, if your code does not need to run at a precise time, WorkManager is a better option

Comment: AlarmManager/WorkManager is always better then the foreground service

by AlarmManager you can set the time and on that time your code will run

Answer (score 0):

For your use case, you will be better off using a `WorkManager` which according to the android documentation, uses `JobScheduler` on API 23+ and a combination of `BroadcastManager` and `AlarmManager` on API 14 - 22.

With a `WorkManager` your jobs will run reliably even if your app exits or the device restarts.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

Comment: not with chinese oems, they wont. they get killed to preserve device's battery life.